# How to make "height" argument dynamic in renderPlot() in Shiny R package

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to figure out how to make "height" variable in renderPlot function in Shiny R package receive a variable from inside renderPlot(). This is my code in server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) { 
output$contents <- renderPlot({
file<-input$file #a CSV file is uploaded

file<-with(file,
                     aggregate(file[, input$metricIn],
                     by=list(period=day,
                     dimension1=file[, input$dimension1In], 
                     dimension2=file[, input$dimension2In]),
                     FUN = input$funIn, na.rm=TRUE))
#input$dimension1In is column name from file
#input$dimension2In is column name from file

#count of facets in the plot to calculate height in renderPlot height argument
facetCount<<-as.numeric(length(unique(file[, input$dimension1In]))) * 100


plot<-reactive({      
  g<-ggplot(data = file, aes_string(x=input$dimension2In,
                                    y=input$metricIn, fill=period))
  plot<-g + geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge()) +
  facet_wrap(as.formula(paste("~", input$dimension1In)),
               scales = "free", ncol=1)
}) #end of reactive
  print(plot())
}, width=1000,
height = facetCount)

}) #end of shinyServer
```

so my problem is that height argument is renderPlot doesn't see the facetCount variable even when I use <<- assignment inside renderPlot.

I want to make height dynamic because if there're a lot of facets to plot I want plot height to adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

When the height of your plot depends only on some input value then please follow the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408144/r-shiny-plot-with-dynamical-size). The main change is to use `uiOutput` instead of `plotOutput` in ui.R file and therefore also wrap `plotOutput` in `renderUI` in server.R file.

When the height of your plot is calculated on the server side, like in your example above, you additionally need to add a function call to the `height` parameter in `plotOutput`. I think this is required, because the height parameter is used by Shiny before making the actual plot. The example below worked for me.

ui.R:

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel("The plot height depends on a calculated value"),
    # Sidebar with a slider input for a number
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            sliderInput("dimension1In",
                        "Choose a number:",
                        min = 20,
                        max = 50,
                        value = 30)
            ),
        # use uiOutput instead of plotOutput directly
        mainPanel(
            uiOutput('ui_plot')
        )
    )
))
```

server.R:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    # instead of global assignment use reactive values
    values <- reactiveValues()
    # function where you do all the processing, e.g. read file, get data from it
    file_processing <- function() {
        # imagine this coefficient comes from your file
        coefficient <- 10
        return(coefficient)
    }
    # this function defines a height of your plot
    plot_height <- function() {
        # calculate values$facetCount
        values$facetCount <- as.numeric(input$dimension1In) * file_processing()
        return(values$facetCount)
    }
    # this function defines your plot, which depends on input$dimension1In
    output$contents <- renderPlot({
        plot(1:input$dimension1In)
    })
    # wrap plotOutput in renderUI
    output$ui_plot <- renderUI({
        plotOutput("contents", height = plot_height(), width = "100%")
    })

})
```