# Variable height of renderPlot based on user input

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to make variable height of renderPlot based on user input. However, I get Error: object "x" not found:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {

dat5<-reactive({
  D5 %>% 
    filter(Parameter==input$analyte)})

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({

    if (input$graph=='By subject') {
    p<-ggplot(dat5(), aes(x=TALD.hr, y=Value, col=Parameter)) +
    geom_line(aes(group = Parameter),lwd=0.9,show.legend = F) + 
    facet_wrap(as.formula(~Label),ncol=3)+
      guides(shape=FALSE, colour=FALSE)
    }

    print(p)

    x<-ifelse(input$graph=='By subject',length(unique(D5$Label)),length(unique(D5$Cycle2)))

  }, height = function() {x*100},width = 800)
}
```

Comment: Where is your `renderPlot` ? Please provide a complete code.

Comment: Hello Stephane, updated

Comment: Found answer posted here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22408144/r-shiny-plot-with-dynamical-size